# how to retrieve data in database mysql. android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments

How to retrieve data in database MySQL?
The scenario is that: when you click the tab, there is a fragment, that is view the data from database by grid view?

Comment: Please ask only issue you are facing. Not what to to.

Answer (score 0):

In the DatabaseHelper class, you can add the code below and call it in the activity/fragment class.

Suppose that you want a train number from the database, your database name is TRAINS and you use Train_name as a reference.If there are any doubts about the code below you can refer this link. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

```
public String getTrain_No(String Train_name) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query("TRAINS", null, " TRAIN_NAME=?", new String[] { Train_name }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return "DOES NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!Objects.equals(Train_name, cursor.getString(1)))
    {
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    String Train_no = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TRAIN_NO"));
    cursor.close();
    return Train_no;
}
```